# rails: how to prevent slow left outer joins

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-4

Assume you have a data structure with a lot of joint tables.
You obviously want to fetch them efficiently.
So you specify a lot of includes()

This works quite well on the first approach:
the basic table get's fetched,
and rails resolves the joined tables
by making queries based on the ids,
to get in the joined data (which is quite very fast and efficient)

But that approach fails, as soon as you apply some where() query or some order().
Rails changes the fetch strategy then, making it an all big left outer join query.
And that really can be very slow.

The trick is to not use any includes() on the first query,
and then refetch based on the id's you got from that first query,
that time with all the includes applied.

There's a caveat for order() however:
- If you want to order on a related table, you still have to includes() that in the first query.
- by refetching based on id's you loose the order from the first query, so you need to resort your results (in memory)

This worked quite well for me using rails4 and postgresql.

You should have one sql query per joined table,
most of them super fast queries by id.

As an added bonus you might only want to do the second query within a cache block,
as to avoid that second query if you have already rendered it.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You've described your scenario pretty well, however #1 what is it that you ultimately want to do / see? And #2 can you show us an example of your current active record query which illustrates the problem you're having?